# Use both point cloud and laserscan with navigation stack

Tags: navigation, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good Day,

I have a depthimage camera with associated ros package to generate point cloud data on my/points topic and an Rplidar that generates laserscan data on the/scan topic. I have the nav stack working with the laserscan/scan topic but now I also want to use the forward facing depth camera. I review the navigation stack documentation, is it as simple as adding another obstacle layer to cosmap that uses the point cloud /points topic?

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412817/use-both-point-cloud--and-laserscan-with-navigation-stack/) by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 34 on 2023-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Include the following In your costmap_common_params file:

```
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor point_cloud_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: camera_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}

point_cloud_sensor: {
    sensor_frame: camera_link,
    data_type: PointCloud2, 
    topic: rtabmap/depth/color/ground, 
    expected_update_rate: 1.5, 
    marking: true, 
    clearing: true,
    min_obstacle_height: -99999.0,
    max_obstacle_height: 99999.0}
```

---

Originally posted by [chased11](https://answers.ros.org/users/115712/chased11/) with karma: 137 on 2023-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0